# Complex Geometry question about Huybrechts.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I am writing up some notes on Complex Geometry for my own understanding and I stumbled upon something that may be obvious to most but not immediately obvious to me which is why I am asking.

It says "For any function $f$ we have that $$\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}}=\overline{\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\bigg)}."$$

Could someone help me understand this better. So I know $z=x+iy$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and I know $f$ can be written as a sum of its real and imaginary parts. That is, $$f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$

where $u,v: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous real-valued and infinitely differentiable.
So to see why the conjugate can be "pulled out", does conjugating $f$ yield $$f(x,y)=u(x,y)-iv(x,y)$$ and does conjugating $z$ conjugate the $x,y$? I am just a bit confused on conjugating $f$ and $z$. Sorry if I am asking a silly question, I just wanted to know why the conjugate can be pulled out, if this is something super obvious, sorry.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ in terms of $u, v$?

Comment: I do not, does it have anything to do with the C-R equations? but that involves $f$ being holomorphic. Here I am just working with a function. Since both $u,v$ are functions of $z$ would I differentiate implicitly ? @ArcticChar

Comment: What is your definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}$?

Comment: @ArcticCharis it given by the Jacobian? the 2x2

Comment: sorry if I am very lost, I am trying to learn all this alone.

Comment: I know the differential is given by the Jacobian matrix of $f$ where the components are partials

Comment: No, $df(z)$ is given by the Jacobian. We have $\partial_z=\dfrac12(\partial_x-i\partial_y)$ and $\partial_{\overline{z}}=\dfrac12(\partial_x+i\partial_y)$. This is on pg.2 of Huybrechts.

Comment: that's what I said, the differential of $f$ is given by the Jacobian, the differential is denoted $df(z)$. You don't have to be condescending about it. Im a student/beginner/learner, go easy on me please. @a1402

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to be condescending; was responding to your earlier comment about whether $\partial f/\partial z$ is the Jacobian

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Now you have the definition, can you finish from there (it's a direct calculation)?

Comment: Yes, thanks a million!!! :)

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$

Comment: can I ask, is there any big connection between Eulers formulas and these partials @ArcticChar

Comment: I would say no. @HossienSahebjame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I should really write this answer. Many people have already commented on this and there is another answer. But anyway, I hope this helps.

Write $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$, where $z = x+iy$, with $x$ and $y$ real numbers. We have, by definition

$$\partial_z = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x - i \partial_y)$$
$$\partial_{\bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x + i \partial_y)$$

Hence,

$$\partial_{\bar{z}} \bar{f} = \partial_{\bar{z}} (u - i v) = \frac{1}{2}( \partial_x(u) + \partial_y(v)) - \frac{i}{2}(\partial_x(v) - \partial_y(u))$$

and

$$\partial_z f = \partial_z (u + i v) = \frac{1}{2}( \partial_x(u) + \partial_y(v)) + \frac{i}{2}(\partial_x(v) - \partial_y(u))$$

Taking the complex conjugate on both sides of the last equation and comparing with the second to last equation yields the result.

Comment: so its like a composition then?